# Antithetic Variates in Monte-Carlo simulations (code taking too long to execute)

Tags: random, simulation, finance

I am trying to use the Antithetic Variates method to reduce error in stock price estimates. Essentially, I generate pairs of negatively correlated RV's and use them to simulate stock price. The simulated process mimics daily stock price and has 1258 (5 years) values.

Currently I am trying to run 100 simulations but the code takes forever to execute - 15 minutes and no results.

[image]

I have tried the same for lower number of simulations (5,10 etc) and shorter length (`{i,1,100}` instead of 1257) and it seems to work fine, took just a few seconds to execute.

The 'sims' table is the one giving me trouble. 'test' is the one with just 5 simulations that works just fine.

The price $S(t)$ follows the Black-Scholes formula (screenshot). `ld` and $\sigma$ are constants.

[image]

Does anyone know how I might speed up the process ? I am not sure which part is slowing it down so much. Ideally I would like to run 1000s of simulations.

[image]

```
sims = Table[
  FoldList[Times, {stocks[[1]], stocks[[1]]}, 
   Table[pairs = 
     Table[u = 
       RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[]]; {InverseCDF[
        NormalDistribution[], u], 
       InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], 1 - u]}, {1257}]; 
    exp1 = ld + σ*pairs[[i, 1]]; 
    exp2 = ld + σ*pairs[[i, 2]]; {Exp[exp1], Exp[exp2]}, {i, 1,
      1257}]], {100}]

Dimensions@sims
```

```
test = Table[
   FoldList[Times, {stocks[[1]], stocks[[1]]}, 
    Table[pairs = 
      Table[u = 
        RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[]]; {InverseCDF[
         NormalDistribution[], u], 
        InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], 1 - u]}, {1257}]; 
     exp1 = ld + logshock*pairs[[i, 1]]; 
     exp2 = ld + logshock*pairs[[i, 2]]; {Exp[exp1], Exp[exp2]}, {i, 1, 1257}]], {5}];

Dimensions@test

MatrixForm@test

sim[i_] = test[[i, All]];

Dimensions@sim[1]

ListLinePlot[sim[1][[All, 1]]]

Correlation[sim[1][[All, 1]], sim[1][[All, 2]]]
```

Comment: You have a `Part` error which is visible in your screenshot. Deal with that first. Also you need to provide some values for `stocks` and the other undefined variables. It's unlikely anybody will help improve your code if they cannot simply copy it and run it from a fresh kernel, so you must provide everything needed to run a simple example.

Comment: You can simulate paths of a white noise like this: `Wpaths = RandomFunction[
    WienerProcess[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], {tmin, tmax, dt}, numpaths][
   "Paths"];` You can then create the negatively correlated paths `antiWpaths = MapAt[Minus, Wpaths, {All, All, -1}];`. It's much faster to generate random data in bulk using the second argument (i.e `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000]`) than to generate them one-by-one in a table.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with your code is that you recreate the entire list of pairs each time you compute `exp1` and `exp2`. You should only create them once. Also, as @flinty said in his comment, it is much better to create the entire sample of random variates first and then to use vector operations on the list. So, I would rewrite this portion:

```
l = .1;
σ = .2;

Table[
    pairs=Table[
        u=RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[]];
        {InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[],u],InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[],1-u]},
        {1257}
    ];
    exp1=ld+σ*pairs[[i,1]];
    exp2=ld+σ*pairs[[i,2]];
    {Exp[exp1],Exp[exp2]},
    {i,1, 1257}
]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {52.9558, Null}

as:

```
With[{
    pairs = With[{u=RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[],1257]},
        InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], Transpose[{u,1-u}]]
    ]
    },
    Exp[l + σ pairs]
]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000292, Null}

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. It worked so fast I didn't even need to create the random variates separately.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Thanks for all the help.

```
sims = Table[
FoldList[Times, {stocks[[1]], stocks[[1]]}, 
 With[{pairs = 
    With[{u = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], 1257]}, 
     InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], Transpose[{u, 1 - u}]]]}, 
  Exp[ld + \[Sigma] pairs]]], {100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.053543, Null}